# format for all a table?

Tags: tables, formatting

I have a table like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{here}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
     \caption{Copas}\label{tab1}
      \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
       & H & M & H & M & H & M \\
      \hline
      Vasos & 1,5 & 1,0 & 4,0 & 2,0 & 3,8 & 2,0 \\
      \hline
      Copas & 2,0 & 1,5 & 3,8 & 2,0 & 3,8 & 2,0 \\
      \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \end{table}
\end{document}
```

It is possible to put one format for all the table? For example, I want that all cells have the format `\textsf{...}`, but I don't want to put it for every word.

Comment: I've removed `tabularx` tag since this question does not use `tabularx` at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a new columntype, say, `K`, which uses `\sffamily` and the original `c` type, this requires the `array` package.

`\sffamily` is the enduring font declaration instead of the `\textsf{...}` version, which is limited to the `{...}` pair.

```
\newcolumntype{K}{>{\sffamily\arraybackslash}c}
```

I doubt, that the vertical lines are necessary, but I kept them.

By the way, it's possible to repeat column specifications with `|*{6}{c|}` or `|*{6}{K|}` in this case.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{here} % Useful???
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{K}{>{\sffamily\arraybackslash}c}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Copas}\label{tab1}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|*{6}{K|}}
    \hline
    & H & M & H & M & H & M \\
    \hline
    Vasos & 1,5 & 1,0 & 4,0 & 2,0 & 3,8 & 2,0 \\
    \hline
    Copas & 2,0 & 1,5 & 3,8 & 2,0 & 3,8 & 2,0 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}


\centering
  \caption{Copas}\label{tab2}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|*{6}{K|}}
    \cline{2-7}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & H & M & H & M & H & M \\
    \hline
    Vasos & 1,5 & 1,0 & 4,0 & 2,0 & 3,8 & 2,0 \\
    \hline
    Copas & 2,0 & 1,5 & 3,8 & 2,0 & 3,8 & 2,0 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Some improvements with `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{K}{>{\sffamily\arraybackslash}c}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Copas}\label{tab1}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|*{6}{K|}}
    \hline
    & H & M & H & M & H & M \\
    \hline
    Vasos & 1,5 & 1,0 & 4,0 & 2,0 & 3,8 & 2,0 \\
    \hline
    Copas & 2,0 & 1,5 & 3,8 & 2,0 & 3,8 & 2,0 \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Copas}\label{tab2}

  \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|*{6}{K|}}
    \cline{2-7}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & H & M & H & M & H & M \tabularnewline
    \hline
    Vasos & 1,5 & 1,0 & 4,0 & 2,0 & 3,8 & 2,0 \tabularnewline
    \hline
    Copas & 2,0 & 1,5 & 3,8 & 2,0 & 3,8 & 2,0 \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{table}


\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Copas}\label{tab3}

  \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}*{6}{K}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & H & M & H & M & H & M \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    Vasos & 1,5 & 1,0 & 4,0 & 2,0 & 3,8 & 2,0 \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    Copas & 2,0 & 1,5 & 3,8 & 2,0 & 3,8 & 2,0 \tabularnewline
    \midrule
  \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: easier option: `{ \sffamily \begin{table}...\end{table}}` ;-)

Comment: In my point of view, the caption should be below the table...

Comment: There's no need for `\arraybackslash`, which is needed only if you pass `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft` or `\centering` to a `p`, `m` or `b` column (and actually only the *last* column needs it).